# Local js to use the session from another tab

Tags: javascript

I am loading a file like:

```
firefox my.html
```

In the my.html I have

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="some.js"></script>
```

In a separate tab I am logged in at mysite.com

How could I make a GET request in some.js that accesses urls available only for logged in users at mysite.com. (The log in is session based with a cookie)

Comment: Hopefully you can't, because that would break the entire internet.

Comment: it is unclear what you are trying to achieve

Comment: Well I did and it did not break the Internet. It is quite straighforward, but just with a lot of options.

Comment: Also - yes, it is unclear because the setup is quite complex and I've tried to minimize it to a very specific example, but the idea is to be able to run a script locally from filesystem only if you are currently logged in at a specific site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is somewhat broad, and the various bits of it are mostly covered by other questions. The only part I couldn't find an explicit duplicate for is the sending of cookies. So the three steps you need to take are:

1. Use `XMLHttpRequest` as described in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/247483/http-get-request-in-javascript)
2. Use [withCredentials](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/withCredentials) by setting `xhr.withCredentials = true` so that cookies are sent.
3. Configure *mysite.com* to grant permission to the site triggering the request using CORS as described in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35553666/19068)

Comment: 3. Permissions are granted for CORS. Working on 1 and 2

Comment: It is working to the point that it is sending the correct request, but the response is empty when the XMLHttpRequest is used...

Comment: How are you determining that the response is empty?

Comment: looking at xmlHttp.responseText

Comment: Probably looking at it at the wrong time. You need a [mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45709482/local-js-to-use-the-session-from-another-tab/45709700?noredirect=1#). Probably in a new question.

Comment: found it. I should have added - access-control-allow-credentials 
"true" in the CORS. That one was missing